# How to find out the declared type of an identifier in Java?

Tags: java, class, reflection, runtime, polymorphism

I have a simple class Apple extends from another simple class Fruit.

At run-time, I could use

```
Fruit fruit = new Apple();

fruit.getClass();
```

to get the actual type of fruit object, which is Apple.class.

I could also use `fruit instanceof Apple`, and `fruit instanceof Fruit` to verify if this fruit object is an instance of Apple or Fruit. Both of these 2 expressions return true, which is normal.

But is there a way to determine precisely the declared type of `fruit` identifier? Which in this case is `Fruit`.

Comment: You should describe what effect you want to reach after having that differentiation. I believe there are other ways to solve that original problem.

Comment: I'm curious why you want to know (how `fruit` was declared), and separately, why you don't *already* know (because you have the code in front of you). I'm not coming up with a use case. The object that `fruit` points to **is** an `Apple`. Your interface to it via the `fruit` variable is `Fruit`, but that's a purely compile-time thing.

Comment: What's the point to doing this - you've coded fruit to be Fruit so you already know that's what it is.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments, I asked this question just out of curiosity. I thought if I could know the actual type of the object, it would be possible to know the declared type of the variable who points to the object. But indeed, I haven't found any use case yet. I was maybe thinking the wrong way, like **by passing this fruit variable to a method, how could I know the declaration type of this fruit variable in the method.** I guess I can't and it does not make sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're actually asking a question about the variable declaration of `fruit` rather than the actual runtime type of the object (which is an `Apple` in this case).

I think this is in general a bad idea: you just declared the variable and told the compiler that it is a `Fruit`, so why do you need to now need to find this out?

Just to confuse matters even more, it's worth noting that you can also have multiple variables with different declared types referencing the same object (which is still an Apple):

```
Fruit fruit = new Apple(); // fruit declared as Fruit, but refers to an Apple
Object thing = fruit;      // thing declared as Object, refers to the same Apple
```

If you really want to find out the declared type, then you have a few options:

- Make `fruit` an instance variable, and query the declared type using reflection.
- Do some processing of the source code to find the variable declaration
- Do some processing of the compiled bytecode to find the declaration type (although there is a possibility that an aggressive compiler might even optimise the compile time declaration away altogether, e.g. after realising that fruit can only ever be an Apple in this code)

I think all of these are pretty ugly, so my general advice would be "don't do it".

Comment: Bad idea indeed. It's worth mentioning the variable is a compile time entity. It might not exist at all at runtime, if the compiler optimizes it away.

Comment: thank you @mikera, I think you are right. My question doesn't make much sense. I was wondering that if I could get the actual runtime type of the object, I might also get the type of the declared variable who references this object. But thank you:)

Answer (score 3):

The `Fruit` object doesn't have a declared type. It's the **variable** `fruit` that has its type. Since the only thing you can pass around is a reference to the `Fruit` object, I don't think your request makes much sense. The best you could get is if you had a specific instance variable where your object is stored. You could then reflect on that field and get its declared type with `Field.getType()`.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't: at least not using reflection. Reflection can give you information about an *object* at runtime, as well as fields, methods and classes, but not local variables. If fruit was a field, you could do something like the following:

```
FruitBasket.class.getDeclaredField("fruit").getType();
```