# how to get the declared type of a variable in runtime in Java?

Tags: java, class, object, reflection, runtime

Consider this code

```
class Parent {

}

class Child extends Parent {

}

public class InheritenceExample {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Parent p1 = new Child();
        System.out.println("the class name is "+ p1.getClass().getName());

    }

}
```

I declare `p1` to be of `type Parent`, but assign it to a `Child instance`. when I do `getClass().getName()` I get `Child` as output. how can I get the declared type which is `Parent` in this case?

EDIT: This does not work in all cases: `getClass().getSuperclass().getName()`

consider this code

```
class Parent {

}

class Child extends Parent {

}

class GrandChild extends Child {


}

public class InheritenceExample {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Parent p1 = new GrandChild();
        System.out.println("the class name is "+ p1.getClass().getSuperclass().getName());

    }

}
```

This ouputs `Child` but it must be `Parent`

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294656/how-to-get-the-parent-base-class-object-super-getclass

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find out the declared type of an identifier in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375096/how-to-find-out-the-declared-type-of-an-identifier-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try to use `getClass().getSuperclass()`?

Answer (score 0):

I thing there is no other method to find than just looping over superclasses.

```
Class<?> c = p1.getClass();

while (c.getSuperclass() != Object.class) {
  c = c.getSuperclass();
}

System.out.println("the class name is "+ c.getClass());
```

Comment: probably I have missed p1 variable and also I've edited the post

Comment: and it must be `while (c.getGenericSuperclass() != Object.class) {
     c = (Class) c.getGenericSuperclass();
  }`

Comment: Looping the superclasses searching for what?

Comment: @EJP: you are correct, this is just looping to find the top most class after Object, but this is not the right way for if `Child p1 = new GrandChild();`, it will still output as `Parent`

Answer (score 0):

```
   getClass().getSuperclass().getName()
```

However never do this, this is very bad design

edit:

In your extended version you will need a loop

```
Parent superClass = p1.getClass();
while (superClass.getSuperclass() != Object.class) {
    superClass = superClass.getSuperclass();
}
superClass.getName();
```

Comment: Well if you are implementing different interfaces, multiple inheritance etc. You do have to know what you are doing. getSuperclass calls the superclass above not the base class so to say.

Comment: you need ofcouse to initialise the superClass variable.

Comment: To answer I didn't test it, there might be a few error in there but that is in essence what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This only works if the variable is declared as its superclass.

Answer (score -1):

To get the immediate superclass

```
p1.getClass().getSuperClass();
```

However, in the event you are declaring an interface, you might use

```
        Class[] interfaces = p1.getInterfaces();
        if(interfaces != null){
            for(Class i : interfaces){
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
```